# Why on-screen report shows total of 4 LMDs, but later on one of them is human?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

When LMD Fitz and Jemma check the base cam in episode 14 it shows all 4 (Daisy, Mace, Mack and Coulson) as LMDs, but later Daisy is not one.

How?

Another question. how did they bring that many Daisy replicas into the HQ?

Answer (score 9):

While it's true that Simmons says "all of them" when asked about the LMD's, the on-screen report is SLIGHTLY different.

[image: will the real LMD please stand up?]

Notice that text on the display:

> S[?]Q TRL 922 MEMORY BUFFER - COMPILE ALL REPORT TOTALS: [4] LIFE MODEL DECOYS DETECTED

The display is reporting the *cumulative* total of LMDs that went past the sensor - not the number of LMDS on the screen at the moment.

We learn in the following episode that while Daisy is not an LMD, Fitz is - bringing the count of LMDs that went through the sensor to four.

Comment: Unlikely in that short amount of time. I can't remember if the Zephyr can carry one of those containers or not. I *believe* so. The active LMDs could have loaded it up while everyone was knocked out, then it comes home and is left sitting untouched until someone comes to get it later.

Comment: yeah, sorry - running on no sleep